# Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL: Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for "mail.domain.de" port 587

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp, digital-ocean, sidekiq

I have a `Rails` application hosted over `Digitalocean` server. I am using `email server` from my domain provider(`checkdomain.de`). I set up an email server with the following configurations:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address: "host162.checkdomain.de",
port: 587,
domain: <my-domain>,
authentication: "plain",
enable_starttls_auto: true,
user_name: <my-username>,
password: <my-password>,
:openssl_verify_mode  => 'none'
}
```

I am using `sidekiq` for my background jobs for sending emails. Sometimes, when I try to send `emails` I get the following errors:

```
Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL: Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for "host162.checkdomain.de" port 587
```

OR

```
SocketError: getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Following are the `sidekiq` configurations in my application:

```
sidekiq_config = { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'], password: ENV['REDIS_PASSWORD'] }
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = sidekiq_config
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = sidekiq_config
end
```

When I try to send emails without using `sidekiq` I also got the same errors sometimes.  I am very confused about this issue because I am able to send emails successfully sometimes and sometimes this error occurs without changing anything. I contacted `digitalocean`(server provider) to make sure if all `smtp` ports are working fine and are not blocked by them.
I have seen that this might be an issue due to enabling `IPV6` service over `digitalocean` which causes `smtp` to get blocked. I also have no `firewalls` enabled on my droplet.

For this reason, I have changed configurations of my droplet to prefer `IPV4` over `IPV6` for emails. I have uncommented the following line in `/etc/gai.conf` file and rebooted the system

```
#precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100
```

But, sadly this also didn't help. I am now getting confused about what might be an actual issue to this problem. The only thing that I can try is disabling `IPV6` completely from my droplet manually as `digitalocean` does not allow this to do automatically. I am not sure if this will really be helpful or might have bad effect on the server because We can't bear a downtime for server or it might affect the domain or may cause the domain inaccessible. Sending `emails` is the most crucial part of our application currently I can handle it by retrying to send emails if a failure occurs but this is obviously not a good solution there is a possibility that email is not sent even after retrying many times. Please help me :/

Comment: How frequent is the error? Does the error keep repeating after the first occurrence? Are you seeing the errors in the rails logs or the sidekiq logs? Are you using `deliver_now` or `deliver_later`? Can you easily reproduce it?

Comment: also could you post your Sidekiq configuration initializer?

Comment: @CodyGustafson, It is very frequent. It keeps occurring one/two times after the first attempt. I guess only one out of three attempts is succeeded to send emails. Yes, I can see the errors in both `rails`/`sidekiq` logs. I am using `deliver_now` method. These errors also appear in the `POP` method while fetching `emails`. It is very random only sometimes when system tries to send `emails` these errors occur

Comment: @nuaky, I have updated my answer and added `sidekiq` configurations

Comment: How much load does the server get and how many emails does it send? Under heavy load you may be running out of ports

Comment: There are many other alternatives out there. To name a few, AWS SES, Mailjet, Sendgrid and etc. Try to change to one of them and monitor.

Comment: @Vasfed, The load is not that much. On average 10-15 emails are being sent per day in a noticeable time gap. I think it shouldn't affect by ports

Comment: @ZulhilmiZainudin, Yes, I have tried Sendgrid and it is already working fine with that but `Sendgrid` and such services send the emails into `Spam` folder and allows only 100 emails per day on a basic account. It would be great if I can use the default `mail host` from the domain provider as it is given by `domain host provider` and is free to send emails and also don't send emails into spam

Comment: Temporary substitute mail server name with its IP address to check if there's really a name resolution issues

Comment: @LyzardKyng , its a little odd question. Can you please tell, how can i find the IP address of mail server ‘host162.checkdomain.de’?

Comment: Use `dig host162.checkdomain.de` or simply `ping host162.checkdomain.de`. It reveals `46.4.18.96`

Comment: You can also try to use *dedicated* MX servers `m1.checkdomain.de` or `m2.checkdomain.de`. Use them if you can log on there, I think they're more reliable. I would ask a sysadmin of `host162.checkdomain.de` - I don't like some of its public services' settings.